# Selecting a specific opengl32.dll file at load time

Tags: c++, dll, opengl, mesa

Depending on the graphics card in a computer, I want my application to either pick the existing opengl32.dll (located in `C:\Windows\System32`), or a Mesa\software fallback `opengl32.dll`. Is it possible to do this at load time, or is this out of my control?

If not, is it possible to execute my own code at all before `.dll` files are loaded in a windows application (my backup solutions is to simply rename the software `.dll` file contained in the same dirextory as my executable) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use delay loading. This is a very simple compiler flag. Behind the scenes, it will generate the LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress calls for you.

Sinde the actual loading of `opengl32.dll` will now be delayed to the first call of an OpenGL funciton, you have time to call `SetDllDirectory`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out `LoadLibrary(Ex)`.

Comment: Worked in my real project, but not in my prototype project. Good enough.